# Is there an opposite to "\n" in C#?

Tags: c#

Just trying to draw a grid in a console app but the way I have it set up this code would be the easiest.

```
grid = grid + closeCell + "\n" + cells.ElementAt(x) + "\go up?";
```

Comment: So you have a string and want to transform it into another string at other position than the end? I.e. add characters in the middle, at a specific index?

Comment: What do you want your ouput to look like?

Comment: There is in fact a way to do that on recent versions of Windows, which support [virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) for the console. ESC M (`\x1BM`) would do it -- *if* the console has support, of course, which is not a given. For drawing a grid it doesn't seem necessary to rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no character for this you can include in a string that will do what you want for the console.

There is a way to go back up via `SetCursorPosition()`, but it's not how this is normally handled. Instead, you change the order in which you look at the data, so all the data from a particular horizontal row is handled at once.